# How to eliminate Escape character from a string

Tags: c#

I have a `Json` saved in database as string:

```
"{ \"path\" : \"a.crx\", \"uniteDeVolume\" : \"g or ml\", \"unites\" :     \"Acts/Volume\", \"nbIndevMin\" : \"20\", \"nbJours\" : \"6 to 7\", \"ventilDepart\" : \"20051\" }"
```

When I want to read this field from database, and to deserialize to BsonDocument, the returned value is

```
"\"{ \\\"path\\\" : \\\"a.crx\\\", \\\"uniteDeVolume\\\" : \\\"g or ml\\\", \\\"unites\\\" : \\\"Acts/Volume\\\", \\\"nbIndevMin\\\" : \\\"20\\\", \\\"nbJours\\\" : \\\"6 to 7\\\", \\\"ventilDepart\\\" : \\\"20051\\\" }\""
```

How to eleminate the escape characters?

Comment: It looks like it accidentally got escaped before it was stored in the database. Can you prevent that from happening?

Comment: How did you get the second string? Is it shown by debugger or saved in a file, where you can view it? Please provide some code, which does the processing.

Comment: Before storing in the database, I convert a BsonDocument to Json. So it's stored as string with one \ in front of every "

Comment: @ZHE.ZHAO Do you *really* need to convert it to JSON to store it in the database, when what you need is a BsonDocument?

Comment: Yes...database administrator created a string type field to save my bsondocument...

Comment: @ZHE.ZHAO The raw BsonDocument is a string already, there is no need to encode it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use Regex from 'System.Text.RegularExpressions'

```
var escapedString ="\"{ \\\"path\\\" : \\\"a.crx\\\", \\\"uniteDeVolume\\\" : \\\"g or ml\\\", \\\"unites\\\" : \\\"Acts/Volume\\\", \\\"nbIndevMin\\\" : \\\"20\\\", \\\"nbJours\\\" : \\\"6 to 7\\\", \\\"ventilDepart\\\" : \\\"20051\\\" }\"";
var unescapedString = Regex.Unescape(escapedString);
```

returns the following

"{ "path" : "a.crx", "uniteDeVolume" : "g or ml", "unites" : "Acts/Volume", "nbIndevMin" : "20", "nbJours" : "6 to 7", "ventilDepart" : "20051" }"

Comment: It seems to miss all the backslashes

Answer (score 0):

You can visit this link, It might help you

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/371232/Escaping-in-Csharp-characters-strings-string-forma

Comment: Please don't post link only answers. Try to quote the relevant parts here so they'll be accessable even if your link goes down.